# Browser not sending cookies via AJAX but otherwise it's perfect

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I am currently having cookies set under **localhost** domain - I'll call it `example.com` (it isn't really `example.com` of course).

My api is at `example.com:8888/api/myApi`

When I request the above api from `example.com:8080` via **ajax**

**i.e** - 
I go to `example.com:8080` in my chrome browser, and i have a js code which sends request to `example.com:8888/api/myApi`

my browser do not send any cookie. I see this from network tab in chrome dev-tools I don't see any cookie under Request Headers Section

On the other hand if I open the same URL in other tab, no other changes, All cookies are sent and I get perfect response.

I do not think it could be cross origin issue as I already getting the following core-origin related headers in response -

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

---

Extra Information -

My Ajax code :

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var data;
                if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                        if (httpRequest.response) {
                            data = httpRequest.response;
                        } else if (httpRequest.responseType && (httpRequest.responseType === '' || httpRequest.responseType === 'text')) {
                            data = httpRequest.responseText;
                        }
                        if (args.dataType && args.dataType === 'json' && typeof data === 'string') {
                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                        }
                        args.done(data, xdr);
                    } else {
                        args.fail(httpRequest);
                    }
                    args.always(httpRequest, data);
                }
            };
            httpRequest.open(args.type, fullUrl);
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', args.contentType);
            httpRequest.responseType = args.dataType;
            httpRequest.send();
```

For Validation - Screenshot of my problem - 
[image: Chrome Devtools Screenshot]

Comment: If your browser has cookies set for `example.com:8080` (from previous sessions) it will send them along when you open the URL via the address bar. If you request it from a different host however, which only works when you allow CORS, cookies are no longer sent along due to the very fact that you allowed CORS. In order to prevent this, you need to set `req.withCredentials = true;` where `req` is the XMLHttpRequest instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Cookies with CORS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365409/setting-cookies-with-cors-requests)

Comment: If you use jQuery, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863571/cors-request-why-are-the-cookies-not-sent

Comment: Will Port change comes under cross origin? @ChrisG
Because same cookies are getting sent when I directly hit the same URL through Browser.
Main domain for all the three things - cookies, api & page is same, so it actually doesn't make sense to not send cookie when called via ajax, but send them when directly hit by user

Comment: A different port is a separate origin, yes. Actively opening something via the address bar is very different from a website loading an arbitrary resource without your knowledge.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365409/setting-cookies-with-cors-requests added withCredentials=true; Cookies were sent. Although for withCredentials we can not use * in Allow-origin header.

Should I delete this question?